# equation error - help please

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}    
\begin{split}
 &\max_{x_{i, j}, \hat{x}_{i,j}, x_i^k} \left\{\pi_{Slave, i, t}(x_{i, j}, \hat{x}_{i,j}, x_i^k, p_k) =\\
 &\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varrho}} W_{j}(\hat{x}_{i, j}(t))\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varepsilon}} U_{j}(x_{i,j}(t)) - \sum_{k=1}^N p_k(t) x_i^k(t)\right\} \\
 &\text{subject to}\\
 &0 \leq x_{i, j} (t)\leq \delta_{i,j}(t)\\
 &\beta_{i,j} C_n(t) \leq \hat{x}_{i,j}(t) \leq \hat{\delta}_{i,j}(t)\\
 &0 \leq x_i^k\leq q_k^i\\
 &\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varepsilon}} x_{i, j} (t) + \sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varrho}}\hat{x}_{i,j}(t) \leq \sum_{k\in N}x_i^k
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, please make your script compilable.

Comment: Please also state your question: "what happens?", "what you expect?", "where you need help?". This is not just for you but for anyone else who might wander onto this question one day, looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks . I've got "Extra }, or forgotten \right. \end{split}" this error message. i don't know what's the problem of \left and \right.

Comment: I'm using TexStudio .

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
\begin{split}
 &\max_{x_{i, j}, \hat{x}_{i,j}, x_i^k} \left\{\pi_{Slave, i, t}(x_{i, j}, \hat{x}_{i,j}, x_i^k, p_k)\right\} =\\
 &\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varrho}} W_{j}(\hat{x}_{i, j}(t))\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varepsilon}} U_{j}(x_{i,j}(t)) - \sum_{k=1}^N p_k(t) x_i^k(t) \\
 &\text{subject to}\\
 &0 \leq x_{i, j} (t)\leq \delta_{i,j}(t)\\
 &\beta_{i,j} C_n(t) \leq \hat{x}_{i,j}(t) \leq \hat{\delta}_{i,j}(t)\\
 &0 \leq x_i^k\leq q_k^i\\
 &\sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varepsilon}} x_{i, j} (t) + \sum_{j \in \Psi_{\varrho}}\hat{x}_{i,j}(t) \leq \sum_{k\in N}x_i^k
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. I've got this error "Extra }, or forgotten \right. \end{split}" , I'm using TexStudio

Comment: With MikTeX, I have no compilation errors regardless of the compilation engine. Do you have MikTeX or TeXlive?

Comment: yes I have MikeTex but i used to use TexStudio. there is any different in the compilation ?

Comment: Normally the editor does not have any importance on the compilation. Which version of MikTeX do you have? Is it up to date?

Comment: I'm using MikeTex 2.9.

Comment: Update with the console, certainly some of your packages are no longer up to date.

Comment: it's up to date , when i use the example you gave me it works. but when i use it in my article, it gives me the error .

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{array}

Comment: \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage {capt-of}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

Comment: It is therefore another problem: that of the class used, which is no longer the same: `IEEEtran`. Ask another question so that users who know this class (I don't know it) can help you.